# To update or not to update Tango tablet

Tags: google-project-tango

I am running in a corporate environment without WiFi, so I don't get OTA updates unless I bring my device home.  After reading about problems with onFrameAvailable() callbacks in the past month I became skeptical of doing any updating for the time being.  I currently have at least one update available, but I have declined.  My device is running:

```
Project Tango Core: 1.10:2015.03.27-kalman-release-0...
Build number: KOT49H.150309
Image frame format: RGBA
```

So the question is, should I update?  Or should I bury my head in the sand for a while and wait?

A related question (that maybe should be posted separately) is, how many more times will the image format change?  Should we code as though the format will change with every new release?  Will the format always be listed in the Release Notes?  (It is for new Leibniz, YUV420SP.  But it wasn't for either Jacobi or Kelvin when it switched to RGBA.)

Comment: Upvoted - this is a legitimate question - crickets is not a legitimate response

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update safely to L or M, though you will have to change to YUV420SP (NV21) if you were using RGB before. There was also an issue with the K release that resulted in the image buffer not being filled out properly. That's probably the source of the concern you've seen on the internet. However, I'm surprised that `onFrameAvailable` worked for you in K, you list that as your current release, the image buffer returned should have been `null`.

As for future format changes, the format for the color image in L is NV21 and that should that way for some time. This is already confirmed for the M and N releases. There is a chance that the format switches to YV12 in the future to be in full compliance with the Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD), but there will be clear communication around that. Tango is also going to provide sample code to convert from that format to RBG when the switch is made.